# UITableViewActionRow change font

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've created below actionRow and changed background. However i can't seem figure out how to change the font in the two `UITableViewActionRow`. How can i change the font?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?  {
    // 1


    var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Redigér" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

    })
    shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#C7C7CC")



    // 3
    var rateAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Slet" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

    })

    rateAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#EA4741")

    // 5
    return [shareAction,rateAction]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily (directly) change the font properties for the row action text.

The best you could do is use UIAppearance to alter a (row action) button's font, but you need to selectively limit it to the row action buttons.  This means delving into the private view hierarchy to only change the appearance of those view's buttons.

Naturally, this is fragile, and will break when internal (view) class names change.